# Code to remove columns in a (fasta) file with more than 90% '-' characters in that column

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

**Context:**

This script reads in a fasta file, counts the number '-' characters, alphabetic characters and total characters for each sequence (sequence descriptions are on lines marked with '>'), and then prints out a processed file with columns where 90% (or more) of '-' characters are removed.

I've tested it with smaller alignments and it worked fine, but it's currently been running for around 4 hours on one alignment (220Mb), which seems slow and probably inefficient.

**The script:**

```
import sys
from Bio import AlignIO

alignment = AlignIO.read(open(sys.argv[1]), "fasta")
length =  alignment.get_alignment_length()

tofilter = []

for i in range(length):
    counterofgaps=0
    counterofsites=0
    counteroftotal=0
    for record in alignment:
        for site in record.seq[i]:
            if site == '-':
                counterofgaps +=1
                counteroftotal +=1
            elif site.isalpha():
                counterofsites +=1
                counteroftotal +=1
    Fractionofgaps = counterofgaps/counteroftotal * 100
    if Fractionofgaps >=90:
        tofilter.append(i)

for record in alignment:
    print ('>' + record.id)
    for i in range(length):
        if i not in tofilter:
            print (record.seq[i], end ='')
    print()
```

Comment: Have you tried running this on smaller alignments? On what Python version are you running this? Would parsing this with `SeqIO.parse` instead help?

Comment: Python 3.7.2, yes I have tried on smaller alignments it works. would SeqIO.parse be quicker?

Comment: @Biomage, Can you share a pastebin.com link with some testable fragement from your input fasta file?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2Ce7mQJa

Comment: @Biomage, I don't understand why the current approach should skip the consecutive columns even if they are not `-` char. Potentially, all records that fall into crucial condition "`>= 90`% of `-` chars " can have those `-` chars (gaps) as the **rightmost** sequence and alpha chars - as **leftmost**, at the very start. But in such case - all alpha letters would be skipped. Why is that logic correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your comment, the sequences are consecutive and aligned, so no sequences are more left or right than others. The current code should remove any column (in it's entirety) i. e the same position in all sequences, if 90% of the characters in that position (column) are - characters. Are you suggesting that isn't happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disregarding using a better parser ([biopython's SeqIO](http://python.omics.wiki/biopython/examples/read-fasta)), here are some immediate speed boosts due to better use of vanilla Python:

You don't actually need the `counterofsites` at all. If you only want the fraction of `'-'`, this is the same as the average of a sequence of `1` and `0`, where the value is `1` (or equivalently, `True`) if the character is `'-'`:

```
from statistics import mean

def gap_fraction(alignment, i):
    return mean(site == "-" for record in alignment for site in record.seq[i])
```

This uses a [generator expression](https://djangostars.com/blog/list-comprehensions-and-generator-expressions/) to flatten the sites.

The other improvement is using a `set` instead of a `list` for the to be filtered elements. This is needed since you later do `if i not in tofilter`, which needs to scan through the whole list in the worst case. With a set this is immediate, i.e. it is \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ instead of \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$. You will only see a real difference if your number of columns to filter gets large (>>100), though.

```
to_filter = {i for i in range(length) if gap_fraction(alignment, i) > 0.9}
```

I also used a [set comprehension](https://medium.com/@joshuapaulrobin/set-comprehension-in-python3-for-beginners-80561a9b4007) to make this a lot shorter and followed Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends using `lower_case_with_underscores` for variables and functions.

You should also keep your calling code under a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script form another script without running the code.